# Flexbox list with remaining width, ellipsis and some content on a new line

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width

I'm trying to learn `flexbox`, but I'm struggling to understand the concept. I want to create a list of e-mails where every item is a flexbox container (see underneath).

[image: example]

Rules:

- The tag is optional but if it is shown, it's shown directly next to the name.
- The date is always there, the width varries
- The Name of the person fills the remaining space. If it becomes to big it is truncated.
- The space between the name and the tag is always 5px
- The mail subject is shown on a new line and is also truncated

My attempt so far: https://jsbin.com/sepobipiwa/edit?html,css,output

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
html {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.name {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.tag {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.subject {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #888;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="name">John Doe</div>
        <div class="date">14:50</div>
        <div class="subject">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="name">Marrie Antoinette</div>
        <div class="tag">Concept</div>
        <div class="date">16:01</div>
        <div class="subject">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="name">Someone with a long name</div>
        <div class="tag">tag</div>
        <div class="date">18:50</div>
        <div class="subject">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="name">Someone with a long name</div>
        <div class="tag">concept</div>
        <div class="date">yesterday</div>
        <div class="subject">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I did this to your code:

1. Made your `flexbox` to *wrap* by adding `flex-wrap: wrap` to the `li`
2. Forced the `subject` to the next line by telling it to take the *full available width* in the row by giving it `flex-basis: 100%`
3. Add `margin-left: auto` to place the `date` to the right-most end.
4. To finish it up, you can add these styles to `name` and `subject` to get the *ellispsis* woking:

   ```
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
   ```
5. Also added `max-width: 50%` to `name` to adjust the first line.

See demo below:

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
html {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.name {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 50%;
}
.tag {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.subject {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #888;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
.date {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="name">John Doe</div>
        <div class="date">14:50</div>
        <div class="subject">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="name">Marrie Antoinette</div>
        <div class="tag">Concept</div>
        <div class="date">16:01</div>
        <div class="subject">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="name">Someone with a long name</div>
        <div class="tag">tag</div>
        <div class="date">18:50</div>
        <div class="subject">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="name">Someone with a long name</div>
        <div class="tag">concept</div>
        <div class="date">yesterday</div>
        <div class="subject">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Suggestion**:

You should edit you markup and create a *wrapper* for the first row that contains the `name`,`tag` and `date` which is a better design (you can remove the *untidy* `max-width: 50%` used above) - see demo below:

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
html {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.name {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tag {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.subject {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #888;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
.date {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="header">
          <div class="name">John Doe</div>
          <div class="date">14:50</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subject">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="header">
          <div class="name">Marrie Antoinette</div>
          <div class="tag">Concept</div>
          <div class="date">16:01</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subject">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="header">
          <div class="name">Someone with a long name</div>
          <div class="tag">tag</div>
          <div class="date">18:50</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subject">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="header">
          <div class="name">Someone with a long name</div>
          <div class="tag">concept</div>
          <div class="date">yesterday</div>
        </div>
        <div class="subject">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `max-width` on the name was very clever. That was my sticking point. I was using `flex-basis` to size the name, which enabled the ellipsis, but caused the tag to be separated by more than 5px when the name was too short. Great answer.

Comment: The second snippet is the real solution. it's much better to change the markup :-)

Comment: I like the second snippet (first one is a little bit cheating with the 50%)

Two additional questions:

1. How did you add code snippets to this question :-)
2. Why is the margin between the last name and concept tag more then 5px?

Comment: the margin is 5px itself, when an ellipsis comes it *appears* to be more :)

Comment: I have post a variation of your answer, just as an ilustration of how can be achieved the same result without changing the markup. The **good* solution is yours, but I just wanted to show an alternative for a situation where you can't change the markup.

Comment: @kukkuz if I change the html a little bit I see different margins between the ellipsis and the tag. There must be something else going on?

Comment: Sorry forgot the link to show it: https://jsbin.com/busilezihu/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @klaasjansen no :) Because of the ellipsis, it *appears* to be different margins - you can inspect the elements to check it...

Answer (score 2):

Just an extension on kukkuz excelent answer.

Here , we are acheiving the same results, but without needing to change the markup. (Some how trickier, but sometimes you just can change your markup).

What you really need is to get rid of flex-wrap and set all the first 3 elements in a single row. One alternative is to set the *subject* element outside of the flex container, positioning it absolute. The remains of the modifications are only to recover the broken layout.

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}
html {
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: baseline;
  padding: 20px 0px 40px 0px;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
.name {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.tag {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.subject {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #888;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.date {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="name">John Doe</div>
        <div class="date">14:50</div>
        <div class="subject">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="name">Marrie Antoinette</div>
        <div class="tag">Concept</div>
        <div class="date">16:01</div>
        <div class="subject">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="name">Someone with a long name</div>
        <div class="tag">tag</div>
        <div class="date">18:50</div>
        <div class="subject">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="name">Someone with a long name</div>
        <div class="tag">concept</div>
        <div class="date">yesterday</div>
        <div class="subject">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, you're using a hack to position it absolute. Because of this hack you also need the max-width: 90%. That's not perfect...

Comment: You are right, The 90% max-width is not the best solution. I have changed the horizontal padding in the li to horizontal margin. This way, the max-size is 100%, that makes more sense.

Comment: Now I need an extra wrapper to create the padding, but I like the idea.

Comment: Do you really need the padding ? Isn't the margin giving the same result ?